# Nginx fastcgi_cache not caching anything

Tags: nginx

I have a Nginx server setup which has fastcgi_cache enabled but nothing gets cached at all. The cache folder is empty. I've tried rebuilding nginx several times without any success. It is probably related to my other issue of $args being empty in sub directories, see more here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36349729

Nginx is built with:

```
 --sbin-path=/usr/sbin --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
 --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
 --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
 --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --with-debug --with-http_stub_status_module 
 --with-http_flv_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_dav_module --with-ipv6 --with-http_realip_module
```

nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  2;

pid     /var/log/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include    mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/web.access.log  main;

    fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:250m inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush  on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;

    client_max_body_size 200M;

    # If your domain names are long, increase this parameter.
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
}
```

server conf:

```
server {    
    listen      *:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    # The Document Root
    root        /home/www-data/public_html; 
    error_log   /var/log/example.com.err;
    access_log  /var/log/example.com.log main;


    index   index.php

    set $skip_cache 0;

    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }


    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-json/.*") {
        set $skip_cache 0;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 31d;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

        fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
        fastcgi_cache_valid  24h;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
}
```